# UIBarButtonItem not changing its state from 'Edit' to 'Done' , when i click on 'Edit' button

Tags: uinavigationbar, xcode4.3, uibarbuttonitem

I am implementing `commitEditingStyle:`. When I click on Edit button on navigation bar swipe to delete button will arrive and everything works fine.
Problem is that when i click on the 'Edit' i want to change that button to 'Done' , and when i click on 'Done' those delete buttons on table view cell should disappear , how can i do this i am newbie please guide me where i did the mistake.

Code snippets are shown below:-

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{       
     UIToolbar* tools = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 133, 44.01)];
     NSMutableArray* buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];

     UIBarButtonItem* bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCompose target:self action:@selector(ComposeBtn)];
     bi.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
     [buttons addObject:bi];
     [bi release];

     bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
          initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
     [buttons addObject:bi];
     [bi release];

     bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
          initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit target:self action:@selector(setEditing:)];
     bi.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
     [buttons addObject:bi];
     [bi release];

     [tools setItems:buttons animated:NO];
     [buttons release];

     self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:tools];
     [tools release];
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}

- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [self.listOfFilesTblView setEditing:editing animated:animated];
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}
```

If I use below line of code evrything works fine.

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=self.editButtonItem;
```

But I want 2 buttons on navigation bar, 1)Edit 2)Compose. 
Please guide me what i am missing here.Thanks in advance.